# When to use lambda, when to use Proc.new?

Tags: ruby, lambda, proc

In Ruby 1.8, there are subtle differences between proc/lambda on the one hand, and `Proc.new` on the other.

- What are those differences?
- Can you give guidelines on how to decide which one to choose?
- In Ruby 1.9, proc and lambda are different. What's the deal?

Comment: See also: the Ruby Programming Language book by Matz and Flanagan, it has comprehensively covered this topic. proc behaves like a block - yield semantics, where as lambda behaves like a method - method call semantics. Also return, break, et. all behave diff in procs n lambdas

Comment: Also see a detailed post on [Control flow differences between Ruby Procs and Lambdas](http://www.akshay.cc/blog/2010-02-14-control-flow-differences-between-ruby-procs-and-lambdas.html)

Comment: you have accepted the answer that only says whats the difference between proc and lambda, while the title of your question is when to use those things

Answer (score 384, accepted):

Another important but subtle difference between procs created with `lambda` and procs created with `Proc.new` is how they handle the `return` statement:

- In a `lambda`-created proc, the `return` statement returns only from the proc itself
- In a `Proc.new`-created proc, the `return` statement is a little more surprising: it returns control not just from the proc, **but also from the method enclosing the proc!**

Here's `lambda`-created proc's `return` in action. It behaves in a way that you probably expect:

```
def whowouldwin

  mylambda = lambda {return "Freddy"}
  mylambda.call

  # mylambda gets called and returns "Freddy", and execution
  # continues on the next line

  return "Jason"

end


whowouldwin
#=> "Jason"
```

Now here's a `Proc.new`-created proc's `return` doing the same thing. You're about to see one of those cases where Ruby breaks the much-vaunted Principle of Least Surprise:

```
def whowouldwin2

  myproc = Proc.new {return "Freddy"}
  myproc.call

  # myproc gets called and returns "Freddy", 
  # but also returns control from whowhouldwin2!
  # The line below *never* gets executed.

  return "Jason"

end


whowouldwin2         
#=> "Freddy"
```

Thanks to this surprising behavior (as well as less typing), I tend to favor using `lambda` over `Proc.new` when making procs.

Comment: Then there is also the `proc` method. Is it just a shorthand for `Proc.new`?

Comment: @panzi, yes, [`proc` is equivalent to `Proc.new`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001446)

Comment: @mattdipasquale In my tests, `proc` acts like `lambda` and not like `Proc.new` with regard to return statements. That means the ruby doc is inaccurate.

Comment: @mattdipasquale Sorry I was only half right. `proc` acts like `lambda` in 1.8, but acts like `Proc.new` in 1.9. See Peter Wagenet's answer.

Comment: Why is this "surprising" behavior? A `lambda` is an anonymous method. Since it's a method, it returns a value, and the method that called it can do with it whatever it wants, including ignoring it and returning a different value.  
  
A `Proc` is like pasting in a code snippet. It doesn't act like a method. So when a return happens within the `Proc`, that's just part of the code of the method that called it.

Comment: As pointed out by Arcolye, "Procs in Ruby are drop in code snippets, not methods". From http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/. So it's like the return is in whowouldwin2 itself.

Comment: I believe a major difference is also that `Proc`s don't throw errors when you provide missing/extra arguments, while `lambda`s will throw a `wrong number of arguments` error

Comment: The answer is unclear on this point and Arcoyle's comment above is simply wrong: a `return` in a Proc returns from the context that created the proc, **not the context that called the proc**. This error is everywhere!

Answer (score 95):

To provide further clarification:

Joey says that the return behavior of `Proc.new` is surprising. However when you consider that Proc.new behaves like a block this is not surprising as that is exactly how blocks behave. lambas on the other hand behave more like methods.

This actually explains why Procs are flexible when it comes to arity (number of arguments) whereas lambdas are not. Blocks don't require all their arguments to be provided but methods do (unless a default is provided). While providing lambda argument default is not an option in Ruby 1.8, it is now supported in Ruby 1.9 with the alternative lambda syntax (as noted by webmat):

```
concat = ->(a, b=2){ "#{a}#{b}" }
concat.call(4,5) # => "45"
concat.call(1)   # => "12"
```

And Michiel de Mare (the OP) is incorrect about the Procs and lambda behaving the same with arity in Ruby 1.9. I have verified that they still maintain the behavior from 1.8 as specified above.

`break` statements don't actually make much sense in either Procs or lambdas. In Procs, the break would return you from Proc.new which has already been completed. And it doesn't make any sense to break from a lambda since it's essentially a method, and you would never break from the top level of a method.

`next`, `redo`, and `raise` behave the same in both Procs and lambdas. Whereas `retry` is not allowed in either and will raise an exception.

And finally, the `proc` method should never be used as it is inconsistent and has unexpected behavior. In Ruby 1.8 it actually returns a lambda! In Ruby 1.9 this has been fixed and it returns a Proc. If you want to create a Proc, stick with `Proc.new`.

For more information, I highly recommend O'Reilly's *The Ruby Programming Language* which is my source for most of this information.

Comment: """However when you consider that Proc.new behaves like a block this is not surprising as that is exactly how blocks behave.""" <- block is part of an object, while Proc.new creates an object. Both lambda and Proc.new creates an object whose class is Proc, why diff?

Comment: As of Ruby 2.5, `break` from Procs raises `LocalJumpError`, whereas `break` from lambdas behaves just like `return` (*i.e.*, `return nil`).

Answer (score 42):

I found [this page](http://raulparolari.com/Ruby2/lambda_Proc) which shows what the difference between `Proc.new` and `lambda` are.  According to the page, the only difference is that a lambda is strict about the number of arguments it accepts, whereas `Proc.new` converts missing arguments to `nil`.  Here is an example IRB session illustrating the difference:

```
irb(main):001:0> l = lambda { |x, y| x + y }
=> #<Proc:0x00007fc605ec0748@(irb):1>
irb(main):002:0> p = Proc.new { |x, y| x + y }
=> #<Proc:0x00007fc605ea8698@(irb):2>
irb(main):003:0> l.call "hello", "world"
=> "helloworld"
irb(main):004:0> p.call "hello", "world"
=> "helloworld"
irb(main):005:0> l.call "hello"
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
    from (irb):1
    from (irb):5:in `call'
    from (irb):5
    from :0
irb(main):006:0> p.call "hello"
TypeError: can't convert nil into String
    from (irb):2:in `+'
    from (irb):2
    from (irb):6:in `call'
    from (irb):6
    from :0
```

The page also recommends using lambda unless you specifically want the error tolerant behavior.  I agree with this sentiment.  Using a lambda seems a tad more concise, and with such an insignificant difference, it seems the better choice in the average situation.

As for Ruby 1.9, sorry, I haven't looked into 1.9 yet, but I don't imagine they would change it all that much (don't take my word for it though, it seems you have heard of some changes, so I am probably wrong there).

Comment: procs also return differently than lambdas.

Comment: """Proc.new converts missing arguments to nil""" Proc.new also ignores extra arguments (of course lambda complains this with an error).

Answer (score 15):

Proc is older, but the semantics of return are highly counterintuitive to me (at least when I was learning the language) because:

1. If you are using proc, you are most likely using some kind of functional paradigm.
2. Proc can return out of the enclosing scope (see previous responses), which is a goto basically, and highly non-functional in nature.

Lambda is functionally safer and easier to reason about - I always use it instead of proc.

Answer (score 11):

I can't say much about the subtle differences. However, I can point out that Ruby 1.9 now allows optional parameters for lambdas and blocks.

Here's the new syntax for the stabby lambdas under 1.9:

```
stabby = ->(msg='inside the stabby lambda') { puts msg }
```

Ruby 1.8 didn't have that syntax. Neither did the conventional way of declaring blocks/lambdas support optional args:

```
# under 1.8
l = lambda { |msg = 'inside the stabby lambda'|  puts msg }
SyntaxError: compile error
(irb):1: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting tCOLON2 or '[' or '.'
l = lambda { |msg = 'inside the stabby lambda'|  puts msg }
```

Ruby 1.9, however, supports optional arguments even with the old syntax:

```
l = lambda { |msg = 'inside the regular lambda'|  puts msg }
#=> #<Proc:0x0e5dbc@(irb):1 (lambda)>
l.call
#=> inside the regular lambda
l.call('jeez')
#=> jeez
```

If you wanna build Ruby1.9 for Leopard or Linux, check out [this article](http://programblings.com/2008/11/18/installing-ruby-19preview1-on-os-x-leopard/) (shameless self promotion).

Comment: Optional params within lambda's were much needed, I'm glad they've added it in 1.9. I assume blocks can also have optional parameters then too(in 1.9)?

Comment: you're not demonstrating default parameters in blocks, only lambdas

Answer (score 11):

A good way to see it is that lambdas are executed in their own scope (as if it was a method call), while Procs may be viewed as executed inline with the calling method, at least that's a good way of deciding wich one to use in each case.

Answer (score 11):

Short answer: What matters is what `return` does: lambda returns out of itself, and proc returns out of itself AND the function that called it.

What is less clear is why you want to use each. lambda is what we expect things should do in a functional programming sense. It is basically an anonymous method with the current scope automatically bound. Of the two, lambda is the one you should probably be using.

Proc, on the other hand, is really useful for implementing the language itself. For example you can implement "if" statements or "for" loops with them. Any return found in the proc will return out of the method that called it, not the just the "if" statement. This is how languages work, how "if" statements work, so my guess is Ruby uses this under the covers and they just exposed it because it seemed powerful.

You would only really need this if you are creating new language constructs like loops, if-else constructs, etc.

Comment: "lambda returns out of itself, and proc returns out of itself AND the function that called it" is plain wrong and a very common misunderstanding. A proc is a closure and returns from the method that created it. See my full answer elsewhere on the page.

Answer (score 7):

[Closures in Ruby](https://innig.net/software/ruby/closures-in-ruby.html) is a good overview for how blocks, lambda and proc work in Ruby, with Ruby.

Comment: I stopped reading this after I read "a function can't accept multiple blocks -- violating the principle that closures can be passed around freely as values." Blocks are not closures. Procs are, and a function can accept multiple procs.

Answer (score 7):

I didn't notice any comments on the third method in the queston, "proc" which is deprecated, but handled differently in 1.8 and 1.9.

Here's a fairly verbose example that makes it easy to see the differences between the three similar calls:

```
def meth1
  puts "method start"

  pr = lambda { return }
  pr.call

  puts "method end"  
end

def meth2
  puts "method start"

  pr = Proc.new { return }
  pr.call

  puts "method end"  
end

def meth3
  puts "method start"

  pr = proc { return }
  pr.call

  puts "method end"  
end

puts "Using lambda"
meth1
puts "--------"
puts "using Proc.new"
meth2
puts "--------"
puts "using proc"
meth3
```

Comment: Matz had stated that he planned to deprecate it because it was confusing to have proc and Proc.new returning different results. In 1.9 they behave the same though (proc is an alias to Proc.new). http://eigenclass.org/hiki/Changes+in+Ruby+1.9#l47

Comment: @banister : `proc` returned a lambda in 1.8 ; it has now been fixed to return a proc in 1.9 - however this is a breaking change ; hence not recommended to use anymore

Comment: I think the pickaxe says in a footnote somewhere that proc is effectively depricated or something. I don't have the exact page number.

Answer (score 6):

lambda works as expected, like in other languages.

The wired `Proc.new` is surprising and confusing.

The `return` statement in proc created by `Proc.new` will not only return control just from itself, but *also from the method enclosing it*.

```
def some_method
  myproc = Proc.new {return "End."}
  myproc.call

  # Any code below will not get executed!
  # ...
end
```

You can argue that `Proc.new` inserts code into the enclosing method, just like block.
But `Proc.new` creates an object, while block are *part of* an object.

And there is another difference between lambda and `Proc.new`, which is their handling of (wrong) arguments.
lambda complains about it, while `Proc.new` ignores extra arguments or considers the absence of arguments as nil.

```
irb(main):021:0> l = -> (x) { x.to_s }
=> #<Proc:0x8b63750@(irb):21 (lambda)>
irb(main):022:0> p = Proc.new { |x| x.to_s}
=> #<Proc:0x8b59494@(irb):22>
irb(main):025:0> l.call
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
        from (irb):21:in `block in irb_binding'
        from (irb):25:in `call'
        from (irb):25
        from /usr/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
irb(main):026:0> p.call
=> ""
irb(main):049:0> l.call 1, 2
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
        from (irb):47:in `block in irb_binding'
        from (irb):49:in `call'
        from (irb):49
        from /usr/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
irb(main):050:0> p.call 1, 2
=> "1"
```

BTW, `proc` in Ruby 1.8 creates a lambda, while in Ruby 1.9+ behaves like `Proc.new`, which is really confusing.

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on Accordion Guy's response:

Notice that `Proc.new` creates a proc out by being passed a block.  I believe that `lambda {...}` is parsed as a sort of literal, rather than a method call which passes a block.  `return`ing from inside a block attached to a method call will return from the method, not the block, and the `Proc.new` case is an example of this at play.

(This is 1.8.  I don't know how this translates to 1.9.)

Answer (score 3):

I am a bit late on this, but there is one great but little known thing about `Proc.new` not mentioned in comments at all. As by [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Proc.html#method-c-new):

> `Proc::new` may be called without a block only within a method with an attached block, in which case that **block is converted to the `Proc`** object.

That said, `Proc.new` lets to chain yielding methods:

```
def m1
  yield 'Finally!' if block_given?
end

def m2
  m1 &Proc.new
end

m2 { |e| puts e } 
#⇒ Finally!
```

Comment: Interesting, it does the same thing as declaring a `&block` argument in the `def`, but without having to do that in the def arg list.

Answer (score 3):

It's worth emphasizing that `return` in a proc returns from the lexically enclosing method, i.e. *the method where the proc was created*, **not** the method that called the proc. This is a consequence of the closure property of procs. So the following code outputs nothing:

```
def foo
  proc = Proc.new{return}
  foobar(proc)
  puts 'foo'
end

def foobar(proc)
  proc.call
  puts 'foobar'
end

foo
```

Although the proc executes in `foobar`, it was created in `foo` and so the `return` exits `foo`, not just `foobar`. As Charles Caldwell wrote above, it has a GOTO feel to it. In my opinion, `return` is fine in a block that is executed in its lexical context, but is much less intuitive when used in a proc that is executed in a different context.

Answer (score 1):

The difference in behaviour with `return` is IMHO the most important difference between the 2. I also prefer lambda because it's less typing than Proc.new :-)

Comment: To update:  procs can now be created using `proc {}`. I'm not sure when this went into effect, but it's (slightly) easier than having to type Proc.new.