# Are there any "simple" explanations of what procs and lambdas are in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, lambda, proc-object

Are there any "simple" explanations of what procs and lambdas are in Ruby?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lambdas (which exist in other languages as well) are like ad hoc functions, created only for a simple use rather than to perform some complex actions.

When you use a method like `Array#collect` that takes a block in `{}`, you're essentially creating a lambda/proc/block for only the use of that method.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
# Using a proc that returns its argument squared
# Array#collect runs the block for each item in the array.
a.collect {|n| n**2 } # => [1, 4, 9, 16]
sq = lambda {|n| n**2 } # Storing the lambda to use it later...
sq.call 4 # => 16
```

See [Anonymous functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_functions) on Wikipedia, and some [other SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740046/whats-the-difference-between-a-proc-and-a-lambda-in-ruby/1740083#1740083) for the nuances of `lambda` vs. `Proc`.

Comment: In the above example it could still be done without the lambda. Isn't the collect the same as a for next loop with the block being the body? I'm just trying to see the advantages of using the block.

Comment: Of course you could do it with a for loop, but this is a more elegant and Ruby-ish way to do it. Other methods might be harder to duplicate with a loop.

Comment: Ok, I guess it would be useful to know what things I can do with Lambdas and Procs that would be too verbose otherwise, maybe with an example.

Comment: That in itself is an example. Without, it'd be `aa=[]; for i in 0...(a.length); aa<<a[i]**2; end; aa`

Comment: Ok, thanks, that was a good example. So it makes the code clearer. Thanks