# What are the differences between a proc and lambda?

Tags: ruby

Key differences between proc and lambda?

What is a lambda and what is a proc?

And how are they each used?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between a proc and a lambda in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740046/whats-the-difference-between-a-proc-and-a-lambda-in-ruby)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found few links. These might be helpful for you -

http://www.skorks.com/2010/05/ruby-procs-and-lambdas-and-the-difference-between-them/

also possible duplicate of -

[When to use lambda, when to use Proc.new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626/when-to-use-lambda-when-to-use-proc-new)

additionally taken from the below link -

lambda handles arguments exactly as a Ruby method; pass less or more arguments than the function expects, and you get an ArgumentError. 
Proc.new tolerates errors; if you call it with less arguments than specified, the rest are set to nil; if you specify more, the ones in excess are ignored.

http://raulparolari.com/Ruby2/lambda_Proc