# Need a memorable explanation of a proc and lambda

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've tried reading about procs and lambda's but I have to keep re-reading the definition.

Can someone explain it to me in a way that is clear and memorable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few resources:

- [When to use lambda, when to use Proc.new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626/when-to-use-lambda-when-to-use-proc-new)
- [Understanding Ruby Blocks, Procs and Lambdas](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/)

There's also an entire chapter in the [Read Ruby 1.9 book](http://readruby.io/closures)

Comment: didn't realize the book was viewable, even better!

Answer (score 8):

Edited: After reading other good answers here, I offer the following distillation that might save you some re-reading:

```
(l)ambda -  
(L)ocal return  
(L)ooks at the arguments  

(p)roc -  
(P)ops you out of the method when it returns.  
(P)ermits different arguments
```

---

Einstein said to "... make things as simple as possible, but no simpler."  If he had stack overflow, he would have pointed you here:

[What are the differences between a proc and lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635009/what-are-the-differences-between-a-proc-and-lambda/3635043#3635043)

or here:

[What's the difference between a proc and a lambda in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740046/whats-the-difference-between-a-proc-and-a-lambda-in-ruby)

hth -

Perry

Comment: I like it -- a more memorable version of what I was going for. +1

Comment: Or how about '(P)ops out on returns'?

Answer (score 4):

The way I think about them is that a lambda behaves more like a function and a Proc or block behaves more like a control structure.

I think the best way to understand why the two exist and what the difference is is to understand how each is used. Take this code for example:

```
def find (elem)
  @array.each { |item| return item if item == elem }
  return false
end
```

It's obvious to anyone familiar with Ruby what happens here, but ask yourself what you are returning from when that `return` is called. What you expect, and what happens, is that the method itself returns. Even though we are inside a block of code, it is the *method* returning, not just the block. That is how a Proc behaves, and it's what lets us use an `.each` loop and return from it just like we would in an equivalent `for` loop.

On the other hand, lambdas are like functions. If you return from inside a lambda, it exits only from the lambda.

```
def find (elem)
  l = lambda { |item| return item if item == elem }
  @array.each(&l)
  return false
end
```

Here, the method would always return false due to the final line not being bypassed by a `return` call in the lambda. Lambdas are functions and return from themselves, whereas Procs return from the enclosing method.

So, Procs and blocks and return from the method using them (like a loop would), while lambdas (like methods) return from themselves.

Answer (score 2):

`Proc`s behave like blocks. Lambdas behave like methods.

I.e. `return` inside a `Proc` behaves like `return` inside a block and argument binding for `Proc`s works the same as argument binding for blocks. `return` inside a lambda works like `return` inside a method and argument binding for lambdas works the same as argument binding for methods.

Note, however, that lambdas *are* `Proc`s, i.e. they are instances of the `Proc` class. The difference between them is whether `Proc#lambda?` is `true` or `false`.

Note also that in older versions of Ruby, `Kernel#proc` created a lambda and *not* a `Proc`, which was utterly confusing. This has been fixed in modern versions of Ruby, where `Kernel#proc` is now equivalent to `Proc.new` and thus creates a `Proc`.

`Kernel#lambda` and the lambda literal syntax (`->(x, y) { x + y }`) always create a lambda, `Proc.new` always creates a `Proc` and `Kernel#proc` depends on the Ruby version.

Answer (score 1):

In a Proc:

- A return statement returns out of the calling context -- for instance all the way out of the method or context that calls the Proc, rather than just out of the Proc block.
- It does not throw an exception for a incorrect number of arguments passed

In a lambda:

- A return statement returns control to the calling context -- out of the block but not out of the method.
- It throws an exception if the incorrect number of arguments are given, just like a method would.

Answer (score 0):

Like Jorg W Mittag says, Procs behave like blocks, and lambdas behave like methods.

The way I memorize it is "proc" rhymes with "block".