# Yet another proc vs. lambda discussion

Tags: ruby, lambda, proc-object

I thought when you called a proc within a method the return value of the proc would trigger a return from the out block context that called the proc. When I call `test(a_block)` I feel like the `puts "after the block"` should not be executed as there was a return value from the proc. Further... `test(a_block)` and `test(b_block)` behave exactly the same. I thought there was supposed to be a difference here?

```
a_block = Proc.new do
  puts "in the Proc"
  55
end

b_block = lambda do 
  puts "in the lambda"
  66
end

def test(block)

  puts "in test"
  puts block.call
  puts "after the block"
  99 
end

puts test(a_block)
puts test(b_block)
```

Comment: Put 'return' in every block and you'll see the difference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between a proc and a lambda in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740046/whats-the-difference-between-a-proc-and-a-lambda-in-ruby)

Answer (score 1):

> the return value

in your first sentence should read as

> the return statement

Use `return 66` and `return 55` and you will see the light!

A great investigation on Ruby closures can be found here: http://innig.net/software/ruby/closures-in-ruby.rb

Answer (score 0):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740046/whats-the-difference-between-a-proc-and-a-lambda-in-ruby), they should behave entirely the same in your example. The only notable difference is that `lambda` checks the number of arguments when called, whereas `Proc.new` spits out an undefined method error.

Note that I'm not an expert Ruby-ist. I read your question, and then clicked on the first "related" link in the sidebar that looked helpful. Please search more carefully in the future.