# Shouldn't these two Ruby snippets work the same way?

Tags: ruby

In venturing into **Ruby**, I started toying with things like the way Ruby returns the last thing you've mentioned even if it was not after a `return` construct. However, why don't these two snippets work **the same way?** Shouldn't they?

```
module Enumerable
  def palindrome?
    reversed_self = self.reverse
    self.each_with_index {|el,index|
      unless self[index]==reversed_self[index]
        return false ## <-----
      end
    }
    true
  end
end
```

**all good so far: puts ['foo','bar','baz'].palindrome? prints 'false'**

**and**

```
module Enumerable
  def palindrome?
    reversed_self = self.reverse
    self.each_with_index {|el,index|
      unless self[index]==reversed_self[index]
        false ## <------
      end
    }
    true
  end
end
```

**puts ['foo','bar','baz'].palindrome? prints 'true' for some reason**

What's the science behind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite! A `return` from inside a block is different from a `return` inside a lambda, as mentioned in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740046/whats-the-difference-between-a-proc-and-a-lambda-in-ruby/1740083#1740083). When you `return` from inside a block, you're returning from the entire method rather than just the block.

We can illustrate this as follows:

```
return :foo # => LocalJumpError: unexpected return
[1, 2, 3].map { return :foo } # => LocalJumpError: unexpected return
[1, 2, 3].map { :foo } # => [:foo, :foo, :foo]
```

Normally, this doesn't happen with lambdas:

```
l = lambda { return :foo }
l.call # => :foo
[1, 2, 3].map { l.call } # => [:foo, :foo, :foo]
```

But when we try to pass the lambda as a block to the method, the behavior changes back:

```
[1, 2, 3].map &l # => LocalJumpError: unexpected return
```

Comment: So you mean that when there's a `return` clause inside a block we return from the block only? I think you got confused in your answer?

Comment: No, it's exactly the opposite. A return from inside the block tries to return from the enclosing method. I edited my second sentence to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby will return the value of the last executed expression in a method. The `false` in the second version is not the last expression, there's nothing telling Ruby to stop executing at that point so it will chug along until the method ends.

`return` is a way to explicitly say to Ruby to stop executing and return a value.

Answer (score 1):

If no `return` statement is present, then return value of a function is the last value evaluated. In the second snipped the last value is always `true`.

First snippet returns early with `false`. Second does nothing with that `false`, it's discarded.

Comment: It doesn't discard it: assuming the condition is satisfied, the `unless..end` block will evaluate to the `false` inside of it. The point is that the `return` statement will return from the whole method.

Comment: @jtbandes: and then value of that `unless` is discarded :)

Comment: Well alright, it's discarded by the `each`, but not by a property of the language.

Comment: @jtbandes: agree, I could have used better wording.