# Are `return` and `break` useless inside a Ruby block when used as a callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, block

In Rails, [blocks can be used as callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#callback-registration), e.g.:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :login, :email

  before_create {|user| user.name = user.login.capitalize
    if user.name.blank?}
end
```

When a block is used like this, is there any use for `break` and `return`? I'm asking because normally in a block, `break` will break out of the loop, and `return` will return from the enclosing method. But in a callback context, I can't get my head round what that means.

[The Ruby Programming Language](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Ruby-Programming-Language-David-Flanagan/dp/0596516177/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1295126177&sr=8-1) suggests that `return` could cause a `LocalJumpError` but I haven't been able to reproduce this in a Rails callback.

---

**Edit**: with the following code I'd expect a `LocalJumpError`, but all the `return` does is stop the rest of the callback executing.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :login, :email

  before_create do |user|
    return
    user.name = user.login.capitalize
end
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually it's kind of interesting...

When you use before_create in Rails 3, we take the block or lambda that you give us and convert it into a method. We then invoke the method with the current ActiveRecord object, for backwards compatibility with the old Rails approach.

As a result, the following is equivalent to your snippet:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :login, :email

  before_create do
    self.name = login.capitalize if name.blank?
  end
end
```

Because of this behavior, you can call return from the block, and it will behave the same as a return in a normal method (because it *is* a normal method).

In general, `next` in a block "returns" from the block.

The specific behavior of normal blocks is:

- When you call `next`, you are skipping the rest of the block, and returning control to the method that invoked the block.
- When you call `break`, you are skipping the rest of the block, and also immediately returning from the method that invoked the block.

You can see that behavior in normal iterators:

```
value = [1,2,3,4].each do |i|
  next if i == 2
  puts i
end
```

In this case, `value` will be `[1,2,3,4]`, the normal return value of the `each` method, and the output will be:

```
1
3
4
```

In the case of break:

```
value = [1,2,3,4].each do |i|
  break if i == 2
  puts i
end
```

In this case, the `value` will be `nil`, since the `break` also immediately returned from the `each` method. You can force a return with a specific value by using `break n`, which will make `value` the same as `n`. The output in the above case will be:

```
1
```

The important thing is that `next` and `break` do not just apply to iterators, although their semantics are designed to behave like their equivalents in C in the case of iterators.

Comment: Thanks, that actually makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 3):

The operation of `return` within Ruby blocks depends whether the block was constructed with `Proc.new` or `lambda`.

I recommend you read the highest rated answer on this other Stack Overflow question: [When to use lambda, when to use Proc.new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626/when-to-use-lambda-when-to-use-proc-new)

In this case, the block has the properties of one created with `Proc.new`.

Calling `return` in the context of that kind of callback would only make sense if this also made sense (which it obviously doesn't):

```
class Foo
  return "bar"
end
```

Comment: @Andy - thanks. In this case the block is a Proc, but it wasn't constructed with `Proc.new` or `lambda` - it was passed in as a block. Or are you talking about inside `before_create`?

Comment: @Andy - having read that answer, the problem is that in that case it's obvious that `return` will return from the containing method. But what's the containing method if it's in a class definition?

Comment: In this case, the callback is basically a `Proc.new` created block.

Comment: So if I return from that block, what am I returning out of?

Comment: You're returning out of the context where it was created.  This causes a `LocalJumpError` if it's executed in a different context.

Comment: It's probable that the return is causing an error, but is being eaten up by Rails.

Comment: @Andy - of course, I hadn't even considered that :P Ok, I think you've basically cleared up my confusion, thanks!

Comment: Looks like I'm wrong, actually.  Yehuda's answer is better :)

Comment: @Andy - I feel kinda bad but it does look like I need to transfer the accepted answer over :P Really appreciate all your help though!

Comment: Nope, I definitely defer to Yehuda.  I was trying to browse the rails code when answering this, but got a bit lost.