# what are procs and lambdas? practical examples please

Tags: ruby, lambda, block, proc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When to use lambda, when to use Proc.new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626/when-to-use-lambda-when-to-use-proc-new)

(I know it had been asked several times but I couldn't find satisfactory answer)Can somebody please explain Blocks, Procs and Lambdas and why one should be used over other, what are the situation when one should use proc, similar and/or lambda. Also there effect on computer memory. Practical examples please.

Comment: Did you look at this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626/when-to-use-lambda-when-to-use-proc-new ?

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Method_Calls#Understanding_blocks.2C_Procs_and_methods

Comment: What's wrong with one of the first google results on the subject of [understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [Robert Sosinski's Tutorial](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/) or [Learning to Program by Chris Pine](http://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/?Chapter=10).

For more foundation I suggest you read [Why’s (poignant) Guide to Ruby](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/book/). This guide is responsible for creating many of nowadays Ruby's Pro! Make sure to take a look!

***Explanation by [Joey deVilla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/216/joey-devilla)***

Another important but subtle difference is in the way procs created with `lambda` and procs created with `Proc.new` handle the `return` statement:

- In a `lambda`-created proc, the `return` statement returns only from the proc itself
- In a `Proc.new`-created proc, the `return` statement is a little more surprising: it returns control not just from the proc, **but also from the method enclosing the proc!**

Here's `lambda`-created proc's `return` in action. It behaves in a way that you probably expect:

```
def whowouldwin

  mylambda = lambda {return "Freddy"}
  mylambda.call

  # mylambda gets called and returns "Freddy", and execution
  # continues on the next line

  return "Jason"

end


whowouldwin
=> "Jason"
```

Now here's a `Proc.new`-created proc's `return` doing the same thing. You're about to see one of those cases where Ruby breaks the much-vaunted Principle of Least Surprise:

```
def whowouldwin2

  myproc = Proc.new {return "Freddy"}
  myproc.call

  # myproc gets called and returns "Freddy", 
  # but also returns control from whowhouldwin2!
  # The line below *never* gets executed.

  return "Jason"

end


whowouldwin2         
=> "Freddy"
```

Thanks to this surprising behaviour (as well as less typing), I tend to favour using `lambda` over `Proc.new` when making procs.