# What is the purpose of blocks?

Tags: ruby

I've just started on ruby and can't wrap my head around blocks

How is it different from an anonymous function?

On what instance would I want to use it?

And when would I choose it over an anonymous function?

Comment: I don't think we can create an anonymous function without blocks. "Ruby supports anonymous functions by using a syntactical structure called block."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby doesn't *have* anonymous functions like JavaScript (for example) has. Blocks have 3 basic uses:

1. Creating `Proc`s
2. Creating lambdas
3. With functions

An example of where blocks are similar to anonymous functions is here (Ruby and JavaScript).

Ruby:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].each do |e| #do starts the block
  puts e
end #end ends it
```

JS (jQuery):

```
$.each([1,2,3,4,5], function(e) { //Anonymous *function* starts here
  console.log(e);
}); //Ends here
```

The power of Ruby blocks (and anonymous functions) is the fact that they can be passed to *any* method (including those you define). So if I want my own each method, here's how it could be done:

```
class Array
  def my_each
    i = 0
    while(i<self.length)
      yield self[i]
      i+=1
    end
  end
end
```

For example, when you declare a method like this:

```
def foo(&block)
end
```

`block` is a `Proc` object representing the block passed. So `Proc.new`, could look like this:

```
def Proc.new(&block)
  block
end
```

Blocks, by necessity, are bound to a method. They can only be turned into an object by a method like I described above. Although I'm not sure of the exact implementation of `lambda` (it does extra arg checking), but it is the same idea.

So the fundamental idea of a block is this: A block of code, bound to a method, that can either be contained in a `Proc` object by an `&` argument, or called by the `yield` keyword.

Comment: so a block is just a block of code that can be passed to method? What's the difference in using the lambda keyword then? Or is my problem just the vocabulary of the language?

Comment: @wnoveno, this blog post gives a pretty decent explanation: http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/

Comment: @Linuxios, you forgot `i += 1` in your `my_each` ;-) A for loop may be better here...

Comment: @Mischa: Ruby doesn't have `for` loops in the C sense. And the `for` loops it does have are really just calls to `each`.

Comment: `Proc` careted by `lambda` is more like javascript's anonymous function as you can posibbly receive the return value from the proc in a same way you can do in js. `Proc.new` is a slightly different as its return means really return. It's more like just a block if you want to call it. anyway blocks are used for those, and that's the purpose of it

Comment: If you want to know the difference b/w `lambda` and `Proc.new`, this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626/when-to-use-lambda-when-to-use-proc-new

Comment: @Linuxios, I always use `.each do`, so I never realized a classic for loop doesn't exist in Ruby. What a shock!