# Rendering a layout in Rails using a proc raises ArgumentError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is something I don't understand. Why is the first example not working (ArgumentError) but the second?

```
class FooController < ActionController::Base
  layout proc { request[:action] == 'index' ? 'foo' : false }
end

class FooController < ActionController::Base
  layout proc { |controller| request[:action] == 'index' ? 'foo' : false }
end
```

I'm creating a `proc` and NOT a `lambda`. And I always thought only `lambdas` require correct arguments.

Gets the block converted to a `lambda` somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

`proc` can also take args, at least, within `layout` method, it requires the `request` object,
on the other hand, you can read [When to use lambda, when to use Proc.new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626/when-to-use-lambda-when-to-use-proc-new) to see what the difference is between `proc` and `lambda`.

Comment: Well, I know that procs can take arguments but my question was why do I get a ArgumentError. Because procs usually don't care about the number or arguments. `p = Proc.new {}; p.call(1)`

Comment: it not care about, proc can use none args, but in layout method, it requires argments