# How to `break` a outside loop in closure (Proc, lambda)?

Tags: ruby

`loop { break }` can work fine, but

```
block = Proc.new { break }
# or
# block = lambda { break }
loop(&block) # => LocalJumpError: break from proc-closure
```

Is it possible to `break` in a `block variable` ?

Update:

A example to explain more:

```
def odd_loop
    i = 1
    loop do
        yield i
        i += 2
    end
end

def even_loop
    i = 2
    loop do
        yield i
        i += 2
    end
end

# This work
odd_loop do |i|
    puts i
    break if i > 10
end

# This doesn't work
break_greater_10 = Proc.new do |i|
    puts i
    break if i > 10
end

odd_loop(&break_greater_10) # break from proc-closure (LocalJumpError)
even_loop(&break_greater_10) # break from proc-closure (LocalJumpError)
```

As my comprehension, `Proc.new` should work same as block (it can `return` a function from block), but I don't understand why can't break a loop.

P.S. Sorry for my bad english >~<

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: 99% related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626/when-to-use-lambda-when-to-use-proc-new

Comment: @Sergio See update, @tokland I know the different in `Proc.new` and `lambda`, I am asking `break` in `closure`

Answer (score 7):

To solve this problem you could

```
raise StopIteration
```

this worked for me.

Comment: +1 Not only does it work, it's actually used in an [example in the ruby docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/StopIteration.html) to halt a `loop`.

Answer (score 3):

To return from a block you can use the `next` keyword.

```
def foo
  f = Proc.new {next ; p 1}
  f.call
  return 'hello'
end

puts foo     # => 'hello' , without 1
```

Comment: `break` a outside loop is different return from block

Comment: In your case, you can use `lambda` and use `return`, I think `next` is not good for this (although it works)

Comment: This doesn't actually work to halt a `loop` as the OP asked.