# Why do Ruby blocks not have required parameters?

Tags: ruby

While starting with Ruby 2.0, I created a small script that worked with the new keyword parameters. While coding this, the behavior of blocks and lambdas surprised me. Below exercises what I had found:

```
def print_parameters(proc = nil, &block)
  p "Block: #{block.parameters}" if proc.nil?
  p "Lambda: #{proc.parameters}" unless proc.nil?
end

print_parameters(-> (first, second = 'test') {})
print_parameters(&-> (first, second = 'test') {})
print_parameters {|first, second = 'test'|}
```

The results are as follows:

```
"Lambda: [[:req, :first], [:opt, :second]]"
"Block: [[:req, :first], [:opt, :second]]"
"Block: [[:opt, :first], [:opt, :second]]"
```

Why is it that creating a block does not have required parameters but using a lambda or a block created from a lambda does?

Answer (score 2):

The semantics of blocks in Ruby are designed to make them as useful as possible for iterators, like `Integer#times` or `Enumerable#each`. Since blocks do not have required parameters, you can do things like:

```
10.times { puts "Hello!" }
```

...or:

```
10.times { |i| puts i }
```

This is also the reason behind the `next` / `return` distinction in Ruby.

Ruby "lambdas" are different; they are not "optimized" for use as "loop bodies" (though you can use them that way if you want). They are stricter about the number of arguments passed, which potentially can help to catch bugs.

Answer (score 0):

`lambdas` behave more like methods in ruby: when you define a method, if parameter is required that when calling that method you have to supply parameters. Blocks behave more like `procs`: `procs` can declare parameter but they dont require it.

`lambda` syntax actually creates `proc` with rigid arity. if you where to output classes of both variables you will see that both lambda and blocks are instances of `Proc`. `proc`s created using lambda syntax will respond true to `#lambda?` method. Also check out this SO discussion to understand some other behavioral distinction between lambdas and procs. [When to use lambda, when to use Proc.new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626/when-to-use-lambda-when-to-use-proc-new)