# Differences between Named Scopes, Lambdas and Procs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

What is the exact difference between Named Scopes(or Scopes in Rails 4), Lambdas and Procs?

Between Lambda and Proc, which one to choose?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626/when-to-use-lambda-when-to-use-proc-new



http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1. Proc doesn't check the parameters passed, but lambda does**

```
 proc1 = Proc.new { |a, b| a + 5 }

 proc1.call(2)      # call with only one parameter
 => 7               # no error, unless the block uses the 2nd parameter

 lambda1 = lambda { |a, b| a + 5 }

 lambda1.call(2)
 => ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
```

Proc will throw error only if the block uses the second param.

```
 proc2 = Proc.new { |a, b| a + b }

 proc2.call(2)      # call with only one parameter
 => TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Fixnum
```

**2. Proc returns from the calling method, while lambda doesn't**

```
 def meth1
   Proc.new { return 'return from proc' }.call
   return 'return from method'
 end

 puts meth1
 => return from proc

 def meth2
   lambda { return 'return from lambda' }.call
   return 'return from method'
 end

 puts meth2
 => return from method
```

If they are not called inside a method,

```
 proc1 = Proc.new { return "Thank you" } 

 proc1.call 
 => LocalJumpError: unexpected return

 lambda1 = lambda { return "Thank you" } 

 lambda1.call
 => "Thank you"
```

**3. Scopes/Named scopes are a feature of `Rails`**

It is used to specify commonly used queries which can be referenced as method calls on the association objects or models

eg, in user.rb:

```
scope :developers, -> { where(:role => 'developer') }
```

You can use it as

```
@developers = User.developers
```

Scopes are chainable, so you can do queries like

```
@developers = User.developers.where(:age => 40)
```

The scope defined in the example, is exactly same as defining a class method, like below.

```
def self.developers
  where(:role => 'developer')
end
```