# Ruby: Is something like anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, ruby

In JavaScript I can do something like that:

```
var foo = function(){
  var a = 5;
  a = a*a;
  return a;
}();
```

So I can define anonymous function I will use only once. I was trying but my approach is wrong:

```
foo = {
  a = 5
  a = a*a
  return a
}
#=> SyntaxError: unexpected '\n'...

foo = do
  a = 5
  a = a*a
  a
end
#=> SyntaxError: unexpected keyword_do_block...

foo = {
  a = 5
  a = a*a
  a
}()
#=> SyntaxError: unexpected '\n'...
```

Comment: Something like `foo = -> { a = 5; a = a * a; a }.call`?

Comment: This article should be helpful: http://augustl.com/blog/2008/procs_blocks_and_anonymous_functions/

Comment: @shivam Good article

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you could use in Ruby [*lambda*](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-lambda)

```
foo = ->(a) { a * a }
foo.call(4) # => 16
```

[Proc](http://ruby-doc.org//core-1.9.3/Proc.html) objects are blocks of code that have been bound to a set of local variables. Once bound, the code may be called in different contexts and still access those variables.

Read this [When to use lambda, when to use Proc.new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626/when-to-use-lambda-when-to-use-proc-new).