# proc return vs lambda return

Tags: ruby, lambda, proc

Why is Proc in ruby return before executing remaining codes in a method from which Proc was called?

```
def hello
  a = Proc.new{ return }
  a.call
  puts "Hello"
end


def proc
  hello
  puts "Proc"
end
```

Here `return` will skip `puts "Hello"` and prints only `puts "Proc"`

But `lambda` prints `puts "Hello"` as well.

What's the reason for this?

Comment: "What's the reason for this?" - because these are different things with different behaviour. That's one of the differences between them.

Comment: Sometimes you do want to return from the entire thing and not just the block. Contrived and silly example: `def find_even; [1, 2, 3].each {|elem| return elem if elem.even? }; end`. So, if that's the case, use block/proc. if you want the opposite, use lambda.

Comment: I see no `lambda` in the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should see comment in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/723/4576274.

It states

> A lambda is an anonymous method. Since it's a method, it returns a
> value, and the method that called it can do with it whatever it wants,
> including ignoring it and returning a different value.
>
> A Proc is like
> pasting in a code snippet. It doesn't act like a method. So when a
> return happens within the Proc, that's just part of the code of the
> method that called it

Comment: Logical answer.

Comment: The linked answer is 12 years old and already was 9 years old at the moment on this answer. Things have changed meanwhile.